# VBA colon ":" statement delimiter. How does it exactly work?

Tags: vba

What exactly does the colon ":" (statement delimiter) do in VBA?

":" meant as a "newline" fails to explain this behavior:

This 3-lines code compiles successfully:

```
If 1 = 2 Then
    MsgBox "impossible"
Else: MsgBox "OK": End If
```

This 2-lines version fails with "Compile error: Else without If":

```
If 1 = 2 Then: MsgBox "impossible"
Else: MsgBox "OK": End If
```

This 1-line version fails with "Compile error: End If without block If":

```
If 1 = 2 Then: MsgBox "impossible": Else: MsgBox "OK": End If
```

So, how the meaning of ":" be exactly described, compatibly with these behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colon allows you to write a statement on one line, and denotes the end of a valid VBA statement.

However, some colons can be omitted ( or added automatically by the VBA editor ) depending on the occurrence of any `else` statements. The `End if` can also be omitted in some cases

For instance, your one line statement would run if it was written as:

`If 1 = 2 Then MsgBox "impossible" Else: MsgBox "OK"`

Note the absence of the `End if`. Your 2 line statement is syntactically wrong and will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks Nick!  "denotes the end of a valid VBA statement" is the definition that I'll keep in my mind since now, replacing the fallacious "new line"

Comment: I can also see that "If 1 = 2 Then: MsgBox "impossible": Else: MsgBox "OK"" works, and any removing any of its colons works too

Answer (score 2):

The colon is not a replacement for the new line.
It allows you to put several statements on one line, but this still counts as one line for the purpose of grammar.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement#remarks) specifically shows the use of colon with `If`:

> With the single-line form, it is possible to have multiple statements executed as the result of an `If...Then` decision. All statements must be on the same line and separated by colons, as in the following statement:
>
> ```
> If A > 10 Then A = A + 1 : B = B + A : C = C + B
> ```

Where "[single-line form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement#syntax)" is

> ```
> If condition Then [ statements ] [ Else elsestatements ]
> ```

as opposed to the multi-line form

> ```
> If condition Then
>     [ statements ]
> [ ElseIf condition-n Then
>     [ elseifstatements ]]
> [ Else
>     [ elsestatements ]]
> End If
> ```

You put several statement on one line, but you still use the single-line form of the `If` statement, without the `End If`.

Comment: I didn't know about the possibility of Else in a single line form. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Colon `:` allows you to put 2 or more instructions on the same line.
`Then` has 2 syntaxes:

```
If expression Then instruction  'case a
```

or

```
If expression Then              'case b
   somecode
'optional Else / ElseIf
End If
```

It seems for your observations that `Then`needs to be the last instruction in the row to fall into case b.

i find `:` more useful in 2 situations:

With `Select Case`

```
Select Case x
   Case 1: DoThis
   Case 2: DoThat
End Select
```

With `Dim` (if you don't require all Dims to be at the top of procedure)

```
   Dim Somevalue as long: SomeValue = 3
```